# Expectation of the sum of ln(x) squared

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I am trying to derive the bias and variance of $\hat{\mu}_{MLE} = \frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln(x)}}{2\sigma^2n}$, where $x \sim \mathrm{LogNorm}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.  So far I have $$
\mathrm{Bias} = \mu\left(\frac{1-2\sigma^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$ but I am at a bit of a loss  for variance calculation. It seems like I'm stuck at
$$c \times \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\ln(x)}\right)^2\right]$$ where $c$ is some gnarly constant that I've decided to ignore for now.  Can anyone offer some help?

**edit**: I might have figured something out but I could be wrong.  If $x \sim \mathrm{LogNorm}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then b.d. $x=\mathrm{e}^y$ where $y \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu^*=\ln(\mu)-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}, \sigma^{2*}= ...)$

Comment: Hint: If $x$ follows a  log-norm distribution, then $\ln(x)$ follows a normal distribution. And the sum of $n$ normal distributions is again normal.

Comment: @Simon Haha it looks like you beat me to it! great minds think alike! :) thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lognormal likelihood for a sample with known $\sigma$ is $$\mathcal L(\mu \mid \boldsymbol x, \sigma) \propto \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu - \log x_i)^2\right),$$ so the log-likelihood is $$\ell(\mu \mid \boldsymbol x, \sigma) = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu - \log x_i)^2,$$ which has derivative $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \mu} = -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n 2(\mu - \log x_i),$$ whose critical point is at $$\hat\mu = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i.$$  This should be your MLE, not what you wrote.  In fact, your estimator would not make sense if $\sigma$ is very large, which would make your estimate for $\mu$ very small.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much; I did make that mistake and didn't even catch it!

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit worried about that $-\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^n}$. Wouldn't it just be $-\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)} \times \sum_{i=1}^{n}{\cdots}$?

Comment: @JerBear Solving for the critical points means solving for $\partial \ell/\partial \mu = 0$, and since $-1/(2\sigma^2)^n$ is a multiplicative constant with respect to $\mu$, it drops out of the equation, just like saying $c(m - x) = 0$ implies $m = x$.

Comment: Oh no I mean earlier, with $\mathbb{L}(\mu | x, \sigma$). You put  $-\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^\textbf{n}}$ when I think it should just be  $-\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)}$. Like $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}p} \times \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}z}$ would just be $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(p+z)}$, but not $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^\textbf{2}}(p+z)}$

Comment: @JerBear Indeed, you are correct--I have fixed the error; thanks for catching it!